# Check who's blocking you with twitter API

Tags: twitter

is there a way to check who is blocking you with twitter api?

Comment: Think about it.  If there was a way to do this, then you could get around their blocking - it would defeat the purpose of blocking.  If someone is blocking you, then they don't want to hear from you.

Answer (score 5):

If you are blocked by a user that you are following, your user_id will no longer appear in the list of follower ids for that user, which you can retrieve via [GET followers/ids](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/followers/ids).

Answer (score 2):

You can find out who you are blocking using [these calls](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-blocks-blocking-ids), but you can't find out who is blocking you.

Comment: The only 'blocking' functions are through the authenticated user, which only displays his/her relationships.

Comment: Here's an updated link to this API resource: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/blocks/blocking/ids

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/blocks/ids is the updated link